# Import gradle project in Intellij even if the build fails

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to know if there is any way to import a gradle project as a new module from existing sources, even knowing that the gradle script fails. It is starting to piss me off that I have to rename my *build.gradle* file and create an empty one in order to import the project, and then revert that once I got it imported so I can work with it.

Is there any way to circumvent this? I don't see the point of this behaviour, seems logic to me that a project I am working on might not be in a stable state.
Thanks all